# Check if email to/from string contains external domains using regex

Tags: process-builder, regular-expressions

I have a string in Salesforce that contains the to and from addresses of an email, e.g.:

```
From: sender@gmail.com to: (recip1@yahoo.com, recip2@icloud.com)
```

A process should set a picklist to *internal* if that string does only contain @gmail.com and @yahoo.com and set it to *external* if the string contains another domain.

My process builder formula looks like this:

```
 NOT(REGEX([Attachment__c].Sender2__c,'@(?!gmail||yahoo)\\b\\S+'))
```

However, the process always sets the flag to internal right now, no matter if the string contains an external domain or not.

On regextester.com, my expression works correctly:
[image]

How can I make it work in process builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The REGEX formula will match if, and only if, the entire string matches the pattern. What this means is that you need to include a wildcard at the beginning:

```
 NOT(REGEX([Attachment__c].Sender2__c,'.+@(?!gmail|yahoo)\\b\\S+'))
                                       .+ here means match any number of characters
```